# subscribe for multiple alerts at the same time

Tags: alert

I have created an announcements list. Where I post news, events, maintenance information. I have then made a button that is linked to alerts. When the user clicks the button, the usual alert box will pop up and you can then choose from the drop-down menu what you want to be alerted about. news, events or maintenance.

Most end users will want to get alers from at least two of them. Because it is a drop-down, the user can only choose one at a time.

I therefore try to find a solution that allows you to select multiple alert subscriptions at the same time. Do you have any suggestions about possible solutions?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot, please? I can't find a dropdown you are describing.

Comment: The actual drop-down appears when you create a view.
I have attached a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/DF9y1

Comment: I've tried this feature in SharePoint Online and it does not show up. I wonder if it was removed in the later version. Which version are you on?

Comment: It works in SPO as well. Create an announcement list, and then create some views for that list. Now it's important that you click the alert button when you are on that announcement-page.

Comment: Strange. I've done of of these: 1) Created an announcement list 2) Created a choice column. 3) Added multiple list items 4) created a new view that filters by a single choice 5) Clicked on the announcement item and went to the New Alert page. There is no option there :( I had no idea this feature even existed. Sounds very useful to me. I will try to play around with it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to create multiple views with a combined filter. You can call these views like these, for example:

- news
- events
- news and events
- news and maintenance information
- events and maintenance information

I found this information on the drop-down prerequisites on another website:

- This option is only available when you create views by filtering a
  choice column.
- These views will only appear if the choice column is not a system generated column like approval status etc..

Creating a view with a choice-based filter didn't actually work for me. The drop-down does not show up. But I've only tried SharePoint Online.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution as well. It's an OK solution if you have few choices. But it is not scalable. 3 feels like the limit before it escalates out of control.

But thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: There is no other solution to this other than writing custom code. That is  the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You're right, this is probably the only solution without having to write your own code. I mark your answer as solved.